# Need 2 files recovered from a wiped phone

Tags: samsung, data-recovery

I attempted to flash a Samsung S22 Ultra back to the stock ROM (which didn't work), but it did wipe the phone. I didn't realize this until the end. I never exported the backup of the contacts and text messages. Is there any way to recover them? The phone isn't rooted

Comment: If the "wipe" was a regular wipe like it is performed on a factory reset then the used master encryption key was wiped, too which makes any data recovery impossible.